# Newton Raphson for nonlinear overdetermined equations on noisy data

Tags: convergence-divergence, nonlinear-optimization, newton-raphson, noise

I would like to know, whether any improved Newton Raphson method is available for non-linear overdetermined equations (So we use Jacobian matrix and pseudo inverse). Data used as measurements are noisy. The final outputs will be very close by, for eg: if x1,x2,x3,x4 are outputs it will be 200.5,200.51, 200.61,200.53. When I initialize Newton raphson with this values it diverges. I have to give far values to initialize. How to give a good guess for Newton Raphson.

Number of equations are 6 (non-linear, quadratic), number of outputs are 4.

Please guide

Comment: I think writing the equations here may be helpful

Comment: See [this short introduction](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation) to writing typeset mathematical notation here.

Comment: Instead of "solving" an *unknown* problem with a *known* method, I would first try to make the *problem* known, or rather clearly posed, in a mathematically correct form.

Comment: See [stochastic approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stochastic_approximation) for handling noise.

Comment: I have tried stochastic (IEEE paper ) but was not successful.

Answer (score 1):

So, you have $n > 4$ equations
$$f_i(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4)=0 \qquad \text{for} \qquad i=1,2,\cdots,n$$
I should not try to solve the problem using Newton-Raphson but, instead, I should define
$$\Phi(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4)=\sum_{i=1}^n \big[f_i(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4)\big]^2$$and I shall try to minimize $\Phi(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4)$ providing the analytical Jacobian and, if possible, the analytical Hessian.

Comment: Gauss-Newton and Levenberg-Marquardt are some other relevant algorithms to consider for this optimization problem.

Comment: @littleO. I totally agree with you. What I wanted to point out is that optimization is a totally different approach;

Comment: Can you help me further, with the set of equations, Thank you.

Comment: I have tried Levenberg method using fsolve matlab, not successful when noise is there. Errors in results are more